# WTForms, Flask: How to render a RadioField with date- and time-input Fields inside of one of the choices?

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to be able to put other elements inside of the label of WTForms RadioField (e.g. DateField, TimeField or SelectField). Here is the finalized part of the form generated manually:
[image: A finalized form]

Right now my Form looks like:

```
class ApplicationForm(Form):
    """
    Class for parsing application related fields from the form to application objects
    """
    application_name    = StringField(name="applicationName", label="Anwendungsname", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=160), Regexp("^[A-Za-z\-\_\ä\Ä\ö\Ö\ü\Ü\ß\s]+$")])
    beam_id             = StringField(name="beamid", label="BeamID", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=9), Regexp("^A-\d+$")])
    environment         = SelectField(name="environment", label="Anwendungsumgebung", choices=[('Produktivumgebung', 'Produktivumgebung'), ('Abnahmeumgebung', 'Abnahmeumgebung'), ('Testumgebung', 'Testumgebung'), ('Sonstiges', 'Sonstiges')], validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=1, max=25)])
    email_for_report    = EmailField(name="emailForReport", label="Email", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=6, max=50), Email()])
    url                 = URLField(name="url", label="URL", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=5, max=250), URL(), Regexp("^[^?]*$")])
    accessibility       = SelectField(name="accessibility", label="Erreichbarkeit", choices=[('Internet', 'Außerhalb des DB-Netzes (Internet)'), ('Intranet', 'Innerhalb des DB-Netzes (Intranet)')], validators=[Length(min=1, max=25)])
    authorization       = BooleanField(name="authorization", label="Authentifizierung erforderlich", default=False, false_values="off")
    username            = StringField(name="username", label="Benutzername", validators=[validators.optional(), validators.Length(min=2, max=30)])
    password            = PasswordField(name="password", label="Passwort", validators=[validators.optional(), validators.Length(min=8, max=40)])
    schedule            = FormField(ScanScheduleForm, label="Scan starten")

class ScanScheduleForm(Form):
    date_scan           = DateField(name="date-scan", validators=[validators.optional()])
    time_scan           = TimeField(name="time-scan", validators=[validators.optional()])
    target_date         = RadioField(name="target-date", choices=[('asap', 'So schnell wie möglich'), ('appointment', 'Termin')], validators=[validators.optional()])
```

What is the best approach to do so? I also want to be able to automatically validate this form at the end.

Unfortunetly I was not able to render the choices of the RadioField one by one, as it would solve my problem. As the only option to render it one by one is to use the for loop:

```
{% for subfield in entry.form.schedule.form.target_date %}
       {{ subfield }}
       {{ subfield.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

So at the end i have no control about where and how the date_scan and time_scan fields are inserted.